# In iOS 7, is it possible to have a view slide down from a tableview section header?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have been researching this for the better part of a day now, and I am coming to the conclusion that it may not be possible.  Here's what I am trying to do.  I have a TableViewController, and in that I have a table view with one section.  I have set the section header to contain a UIView, and I am leaving the default "sticky" behavior so the section header doesn't scroll with the rows.  I want to introduce a button on the section header that when tapped will cause a second TableView to slide DOWN from the section header.  Basically, I want similar functionality to the notifications window, but I want it to slide out/down from the table's section header.

Thus far, my best attempt involves redrawing the section header, and then calling [self.tableView reloadData], which results in a twitchy effect and the second tableViewController doesn't display correctly. My next thought is to actually use the second TableView as the UIView in the section header, and only display the footer of the second TableView until the user taps the header.  Even if I do this, though, I still can't figure out how to create the slide-down transition.

Any help or ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:` to create the slide down animation.

Comment: This helped me figure out how to make the view slide, thank you!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To slide a View down from above, I finally settled on this code:

```c
-(void) openView

{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
}

-(void) closeView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40-self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
}
```

When closing the view I start with -40 on the y axis because I needed an offset for my work.  If you use this code you may need to play around with the values to get what you need.  I hope this can point someone else in the right direction for a solution to their specific problem.